# How to hide UI Component while recording video in react native?

Tags: react-native, screenshot, video-recording

[image]

I have used [react-native-record-screen](https://github.com/yutasuzuki/react-native-record-screen#readme).

Issue I am facing
When I start recording video I want to hide some UI component from screen while screen is recording like Play | Pause | Stop video recording button.

So When I watch the recorded video, buttons are also being recorded. How to hide such things here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a state variable to do this.

```
const [recording, setRecoring] = useState(false)
```

When you start recording, set this variable to true.

You can either:

Use conditional rendering:

```
if (recording)
return null
else return <UIComponent/>
```

Use conditional styling:

```
<UIComponent style={{
    opacity: recording ? 0 : 1
    }}/>
```

Personally, I prefer conditional rendering.

I don't know what your code is, but from the screenshot, how would you stop recording?
If you want to keep the UIComponent that stops recording, conditional styling is what you should use though. While opacity is 0, TouchableOpacity will still fire.